# pandas and matplotlib errors: 'AxesHostAxes' object has no attribute 'rowNum'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot graphs using pandas DataFrame with with matplotlib inset-axis, but could not make it work. This only happened after I updated my pandas package to version 0.16.2, and now I always receive the following error messages:

'AxesHostAxes' object has no attribute 'rowNum'

The following is my code:

```
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))

    mydata.plot(ax = ax, color = colors[1])
    axins =  inset_axes(ax,
                            width="55%", # width = 30% of parent_bbox
                            height="50%", # height : 1 inch
                            loc = 4,

            )
    mydata[:151].plot(ax = axins, color = colors[1])
```

mydata is a pandas DataFrame. I do get the following graph even with the error message. Anybody knows how to solve this problem?
[image: Output of the graph]

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem before and found the solution here [github_issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10407)

Try to reinstall pandas with:

```
sudo -H pip install pandas==0.15.2
```